# Cannot cast HTMLInputElementClass to HTMLButtonElementClass with IE automation?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

Hi i am trying to click a button using c# but i keep getting a casting error

`Unable to cast COM object of type 'mshtml.HTMLInputElementClass' to class type 'mshtml.HTMLButtonElementClass'`. Instances of types that represent COM components cannot be cast to different types that represent COM components; however they can be cast to interfaces as long as the underlying COM component supports QueryInterface calls for the IID of the interface.

what am i doing wrong?
the code is the following:

```
namespace IEAutomation {
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for IEDriverTest.
    /// </summary>
    /// 
    using mshtml;
    using System.Threading;
    using SHDocVw;
    public class IEDriverTest {
        public IEDriverTest() {
        }



        public void TestGoogle() {


            object o = null;
            SHDocVw.InternetExplorer ie = new
            SHDocVw.InternetExplorerClass();
            IWebBrowserApp wb = (IWebBrowserApp)ie;
            wb.Visible = true;
            //Do anything else with the window here that you wish
            wb.Navigate("https://adwords.google.co.uk/um/Logout", ref o, ref o, ref o, ref o);
            while (wb.Busy) { Thread.Sleep(100); }
            HTMLDocument document = ((HTMLDocument)wb.Document);
            IHTMLElement element = document.getElementById("Email");
            HTMLInputElementClass email = (HTMLInputElementClass)element;
            email.value = "testtestingtton@gmail.com";
            email = null;
            element = document.getElementById("Passwd");
            HTMLInputElementClass pass = (HTMLInputElementClass)element;
            pass.value = "pass";
            pass = null;
            element = document.getElementById("signIn");

            HTMLButtonElementClass subm = (HTMLButtonElementClass)element;//ERROR HERE
            subm.click();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [`<button>`](http://particletree.com/features/rediscovering-the-button-element/) is *not* an [`<input type="submit">`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.4) or `<input type="button">`.

An `<input>` *DOM element* is represented by `mshtml.HTMLInputElementClass` while a `<button>` *DOM element* is represented by `mshtml.HTMLButtonElementClass`. Thus the cast is invalid as an ButtonElement is not assignable (castable) from an InputElement and the different types represent two distinct HTML entities. A "literal" interpretation of the DOM is exposed.

Casting does *not* (and cannot) change the actual object's type. The solution is to treat the object for what it is: `mshtml.HTMLInputElement`.

(It's a good thing [HTMLInputElement also has a `click`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16738/Automating-web-browsing).)

Happy coding.

Comment: Thanks so much, how blind of me, i was certain it was a button.